# Existence of Riemann integral for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was reading the proof of Richard Courant in its book of introduction of Calculus and Analysis for the existence of the Riemann integral for a continuous function. But i can't understand one of the steps presented in the proof.

Here is the idea presented in the book (the idea is longer but i sum it up for the question)
Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on the interval $[a, b]$.
We subdivide the interval $[a, b]$ into n parts by successive points $x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_n$. That subdivition will be called $S_n$. Because of the uniform continuity of $f$, if two successive points differ by less than $\delta(\epsilon)$, the respective values of f will differ by less than $\epsilon$.
We define the following sum $f_n$ based on the subdivision $S_n$:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\Delta x_i$$

In order to prove the existence, is necessary to prove that for a sequence of subdivisions with span tending to zero, the sum converge.

First, we compare to sums $F_N$ and $F_n$, belonging to two different subdivisions $S_N$ and $S_n$, both with span less than $\delta$, where $S_N$ is a refinement of $S_n$.

Let $y_i$ be the points of the subdivision of $S_n$.

Let $x_i$ and $x_{i-1}$ be two successive points of $S_n$. This two points occur among the values $y_j$.
In other words $[x_{i_1},x_{i}]$ can be broken in intervals $[y_{r-1},y_r],\cdots, [y_{s-1},y_s]$.

The contribution of the interval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ to $F_N$ is equal to

$$ \sum_{j=r}^{s}f(\eta_{i})\Delta y_j$$

And the contribution to $f_n$ is equal to

$$ f(\zeta_{i})(x_{i} - x_{i-1})= \sum_{j=1}^{s}f(\zeta_{i})\Delta y_j$$

Finding the difference of tue absolute value of the contributions and using the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous, we get

$$| \sum_{j=r}^{s}[f(\zeta_{i})-f(\eta_{j})] \Delta y_j |≤\sum_{j=r}^{s}\Delta y_j=\epsilon(x_{i} - x_{i-1})$$

*Here is the step that i don't understand*
The book then states than summing the contributions to both sums of every cell, we get

$$|F_N-f_n|≤\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon(x_{i} - x_{i-1})=\epsilon(b-a)$$.

The proof continues from there, but i understand the following steps

- I don't get how from the difference of contributions of one cell, the last inequality follows.

I tried summing from i=1 to n on both sides from the first inequality but i couldn't reach the final inequality.

Thanks in advance for any clarification or explanation.

Comment: *continuous* has two *u*’s

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @Tanner - just as *immaterial* has two *m*'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better notation is $x_{i-1} = y_{r_i} < y_{{r_i}+1} < ...< y_{s_i} = x_i$.

Since

$$\left| \sum_{j=r_i}^{s_i}[f(\zeta_{i})-f(\eta_{j})] \Delta y_j \right|\leqslant\sum_{j=r_i}^{s_i}|f(\zeta_{i})-f(\eta_{j})| \Delta y_j \leqslant\epsilon\sum_{j=r_i}^{s_i}\Delta y_j=\epsilon(x_{i} - x_{i-1}),$$

we have

$$|F_N - F_n| = \left| \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=r_i}^{s_i}[f(\zeta_{i})-f(\eta_{j})] \Delta y_j \right| \leqslant  \sum_{i=1}^n\left| \sum_{j=r_i}^{s_i}[f(\zeta_{i})-f(\eta_{j})] \Delta y_j \right| \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon(x_{i} - x_{i-1})\\ = \epsilon (b-a) $$

Comment: Thanks, your notation helped me a lot

Comment: @CristhianMartinez08: You're welcome.